# CSS Selector for Table Row with X number of Cells

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape some content off of a website and I am having trouble selecting the correct elements.

I'm using Nokogiri, and, as I know CSS best, I am trying to use it to select the data I want.

There is a big table with rows I do not want, but these can change; They are not always row 4, 5, 6, 10, 14 for example.

The only way I can tell if it's a row I want is if the row has `TD` tags in it.
What is the right CSS selector to do this?

```
 # Search for nodes by css
  doc.css('#mainContent p table tr').each do |td|
  throw td
  end
```

---

EDIT:

I'm trying to scrape [boxrec.com/schedule.php](http://boxrec.com/schedule.php?country=WWW&division=&title=&tv=&SUBMIT=Go). I want the rows for each match, but, it's a very large table with numerous rows which aren't the match. The first couple rows of each date section aren't needed, including every other line which has "bout subject to change....", and also spacing rows between days.

SOLUTION:

```
doc.xpath("//table[@align='center'][not(@id) and not(@class)]/tr").each do |trow|

    #Try get the date
    if trow.css('.show_left b').length == 1
      match_date = trow.css('.show_left b').first.content

    end

    if trow.css('td a').length == 2 and trow.css('* > td').length > 10

      first_boxer_td = trow.css('td:nth-child(5)').first
      second_boxer_td = trow.css('td:nth-child(5)').first

      match = {
        :round => trow.css('td:nth-child(3)').first.content.to_i,
        :weight => trow.css('td:nth-child(4)').first.content.to_s,
        :first_boxer_name => first_boxer_td.css('a').first.content.to_s,
        :first_boxer_link => first_boxer_td.css('a').first.attribute('href').to_s,
        :second_boxer_name => second_boxer_td.css('a').first.content.to_s,
        :second_boxer_link => second_boxer_td.css('a').first.attribute('href').to_s,
        :date => Time.parse(match_date)
      }  


      #:Weight => trow.css('td:nth-child(4)').to_s
      #:BoxerA => trow.css('td:nth-child(5)').to_s
      #:BoxerB => trow.css('td:nth-child(9)').to_s    

      myscrape.push(match)

    end
  end
```

Comment: If you want good answers you'll need to provide the page you are scraping or at least some sample html. Also the best way to try stuff like this is in an `irb` session, where you can immidiately see the elements you're trying to scan for and keep adjusting your selectors until you find what you need.

Comment: updated with the site to scrape. I don't know what a irb is.. (interactive ruby session? from googling.. is it easy to set up?)

Comment: IRB is included with Ruby. Try typing `irb` at the terminal command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to tell *how many* `td` elements a `tr` contains, but you can tell if it is empty or not:

```
doc.css('#mainContent p table tr:not(:empty)').each do |td|
  throw td
end
```

Comment: would it possibly be better and easier to do this in steps then. for each tr.... then do count on its td's and if has the required number "do more stuff"

Comment: `doc.css` returns a `NodeSet` which acts like an `Array`. Assigning that to a variable then using `size` on it will return the number of elements found. From there it's easy to add conditional logic.

Comment: this helped me get to the solution and so i marked as correct!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

tr rows with a 4th td

```
doc.xpath('//tr/td[4]/..')
```

another way with css:

```
doc.css('tr').select{|tr| tr.css('td').length >= 4}
```